# How to configure Brackets.io Live Development to use Chromium instead of Chrome on OSX?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, adobe-brackets

I would like to reuse already installed in the system Chromium browser and do not additionally install Chrome (because then I can't use Chromium at the same time - they share one profile folder by default on OSX, also for other reasons)

Here are ideas, the problem is - they are just conceptual, not ready to implement:

- edit Brackets configs (*didn't find much of them*) to call Chromium (how it calls)
- edit Chromium configs (to mimic the Chrome?)
- use dev tools remote debugger and connect to created web-socket
- create link to `Chromium` via: `sudo ln -s ~/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium /usr/bin/google-chrome` *// didn't work*
- connect to the simple static server from the folder (via `httpster`) *// didn't work*

How is it possible to use Chromium instead of Google Chrome to use Brackets' Live Development feature?

Comment: I also tried the simlink option but it didn't work but the thing is that in osx chrome is installed in a different path than linux...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac, Brackets [locates Chrome based on its bundle identifier](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/blob/master/appshell/appshell_extensions_mac.mm#L251). So in theory, if you hack Chromium's `Info.plist` to change its bundle id to `com.google.Chrome` (and I guess remove or patch any copies of Chrome that might collide with that) -- then Brackets should launch Chromium for you.

In the future, Brackets plans to [make this more configurable](https://trello.com/c/MYaUdJOR/508-live-development-w-custom-chrome-install-e-g-canary-portable-chrome-dartium) as an official feature - but it's not there yet.